# Do conquest points count before a planet is invaded?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I get conquest points before my guild is invading a planet. Do those points still count for the planet conquest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do.  You simply lose out on any possible bonus multipliers until the invasion occurs.